# No data in mat-table

Tags: angular, angular-material

Work in Angular 2+. This is my project.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v8tdaz
I dont know what is wrong, but my mat-table not display its content.
I see sort, paginator, filter...but not see data in table.

I see data in console

```
0: {fieldDate: "Fri May 18 2018 17:38:35 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))", fieldHost: "192.168.32.30", fieldEvent: "Active", fieldComent: "Its OK", fieldResult: "true"}
1: {fieldDate: "Fri May 18 2018 17:38:35 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))", fieldHost: "192.168.30.47", fieldEvent: "Bug", fieldComent: "Smth wrong", fieldResult: "false"}
length: 2
```

But in HTML its empty

```
<mat-row _ngcontent-c1="" class="mat-row ng-star-inserted" role="row">
<!---->
</mat-row>
```

> I try display non-material tags in table, its not display too.
>   I suppose, that version of my lib is wrong, but it dosnt work.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things in your project

Firstly,  `public displayedColumns: ['fieldDate', 'fieldHost', 'fieldEvent', 'fieldComent', 'fieldResult'];`

That's not how you assign a string array. I guess you did a syntactical error here. Instead of `=` you provided `:`

So, it should be

```
public displayedColumns = ['fieldDate', 'fieldHost', 'fieldEvent', 'fieldComent', 'fieldResult'];
```

Second, the `displayedColumns` should contain only those columns which you want to display. In your case you are displaying only `fieldDate` column in HTML, and setting 5 columns in the array.

So, this should be

```
public displayedColumns = ['fieldDate'];
```

Here's the working solution for your project - [Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wpmc2q?file=src/app/components/group-audit/form-audit/form-audit.component.ts)